# How to connect to WiFi on Debian 10 (Buster)

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I was looking for how to connect to WiFi on Debian Buster from CLI and I found a tutorial for how to do it.

The tutorial says to scan for network interfaces with the following command:

```
# ip a
```

it lists interfaces `lo` (loopback interface), `eth0`, for the ethernet interface, and `wlx00c14124105`, which is my USB WiFi dongle.

Next, it tells me to scan for networks using:

```
# sudo iwlist wlx00c14124105 scan | grep -i ssid
```

The computer tells me I cannot scan for networks using that interface. That's OK because I know the network I want to connect to.

Then, the tutorial tells me to set up a configuration file for `wpa_supplicant`.

```
# nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The file is as follows:

```
network={
  ssid="my-network-name"
  psk="my-network-password"
}
```

Next, I'm supposed to start up the interface and connect to the network with:

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlx00c14124105 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

It returns:

```
rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
Could not read interface wlx00c14124105 flags: No such device
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlx00c14124105' UP
wlx00c14124105: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

I suume this is an error, but to test:

```
# ping www.google.com
```

does not work. Any help would be very appreciated.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

Comment: Welcome, could you add the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: `Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter` this is the only device connected to the computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. WiFi was blocked by rfkill for some reason, so I unblocked it and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Following the installation guide on [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb).

> Add `non-free` to your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

> Install the `firmware-misc-nonfree` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

> Connect the device to your system. The `rt2800usb` kernel module is automatically loaded for supported devices.

Comment: nothing happened when I plugged in the device.

Comment: @LennonMcLean run `sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb` then scan for AP `sudo iw dev wlx00c14124105 scan | grep SSID`. Are you able to get the wifi networks?

Comment: I get `Command failed: No such device: (-19)`

Comment: Why is that? when I run `ip a` it clearly states that the device exists, but it says that the command failed!